# Need to add dataframes in a excel in iterative format

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a pandas dataframe from dictionary and i need to copy the unique column data to a excel in the same sheet But its just writing one dataframe and doesnt write anything after that Help! 
Below is the code:

```
import pandas
import csv
import os

act_dict = {'bmc': [], 'adc': [], 'volume': []}
with open('/home/laxmi/Downloads/chadaLookuptablevalueWithAdcreferenceAndBmcid.csv','r') as fp:    
contents=csv.reader(fp)
total_count=0
i=0
for row in contents:
    if contents.line_num == 1:
        continue
    data=row
    act_dict['bmc'].append(data[0])
    act_dict['adc'].append(data[1])
    act_dict['volume'].append(data[2])
    total_count+=1
os.chdir("/home/laxmi/Documents/volume_analyser_project")
bmc_data = pandas.DataFrame(act_dict)
count=len(bmc_data.bmc.unique())
l1 = bmc_data.bmc.unique()
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
count1=(len(l1))
startrow=startcol=0
for i in range(count1):
    df_i=bmc_data[bmc_data.bmc==l1[i]]
    df_i.to_excel(writer,startrow=0,startcol=startcol+2,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Could you explain better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to move the save outside the loop. It closes the XLSX file and you won’t be able to write anything else.

Comment: thanks,putting writer.save outside the loop worked for me with writing the incrementing  of column not in the df_i.to_excel(writer,startrow=0,startcol=startcol+2,sheet_name='Sheet1') instead writing it this way   df_i.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow=0,startcol=startcol,index=False)
        startcol=startcol+4

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = bmc_data.bmc.unique()
print(l1)
startcol=startrow = 0
file_name='/home/laxmi/Documents/volume_analyser_project/idmc.xlsx'
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('idmc.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
count1=(len(l1))
print(count1)
for i in range(count1):
    df_i=bmc_data[bmc_data.bmc==l1[i]]
    df_i = df_i.sort_values("adc", axis = 0, ascending = True)
    df_i.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow=0,startcol=startcol,index=False)
    startcol=startcol+4
    print(startrow,startcol)
writer.save()
```